# How do I replace a group of reserved chars into " " in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I want to replace the following reserved chars into spaces:

```
+ - & | ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \
```

This is my code, but it doesn't work. Did I miss anything?

```
keyword = keyword.gsub(/\\+-&\\|!\\(\\)\\{\\}\\[\\]\\^"~\\*\\?:\\\\/, ' ')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what `tr` is for:

```
keyword.tr '-+&|!(){}[]^"~*?:\\', " "
#=> "                                   "
```

Comment: What is the difference between gsub and tr? which is faster? Thanks!

Comment: I would guess that tr is faster (not enough to matter really) but you don't need to worry about escaping

Comment: +1 for going for `tr`. It's an unsung hero. `tr is faster (not enough to matter really)`. Oh yeah? Check out the benchmark. :-) I haven't looked at the source code, but `tr` should translate into C code that is highly efficient and should map closely to instructions in the CPU, based on my days writing in assembly language. `gsub` is going to take a lot more instructions to implement, especially when the regular expression engine is involved.

Comment: yeah, this is a much better solution than mine.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a benchmark showing the speed difference between `gsub` and `tr`:

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'pp'

STR = '+ - & | ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \\'
LONG_STR = STR * 1_000
N = 1_000

puts `ruby -v`

pp STR.gsub(/[+&|!(){}\[\]^"~*:?\\-]/, ' ')
pp STR.tr('-+&|!(){}[]^"~*?:\\', ' ')

Benchmark.bm(5) do |b|
  b.report('gsub') { N.times { LONG_STR.gsub(/[+&|!(){}\[\]^"~*:?\\-]/, ' ') } }
  b.report('tr') { N.times { LONG_STR.tr('+&|!(){}[]^"~*:?\\-', ' ') } }
end
```

And the output:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
"                                   "
"                                   "
          user     system      total        real
gsub  13.300000   0.190000  13.490000 ( 13.524779)
tr     0.080000   0.010000   0.090000 (  0.090045)

ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
"                                   "
"                                   "
            user     system      total        real
gsub   17.890000   0.040000  17.930000 ( 18.016657)
tr      0.270000   0.000000   0.270000 (  0.283021)

ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
"                                   "
"                                   "
            user     system      total        real
gsub    7.310000   0.020000   7.330000 (  7.361403)
tr      0.140000   0.010000   0.150000 (  0.145816)
```

It's interesting that 1.8.7 out-performed 1.9.3. I suspect it's because of the addition of multibyte character support in 1.9+.

I've done several benchmarks with 2.0 and have been very happy with the speed improvements I've seen.

Answer (score 4):

Just do this.

```
keyword.gsub!(/[+\-&|!(){}\[\]^"~*?:\\]/, " ")
```

Check:

```
>> keyword = '+ - & | ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \\'
=> "+ - & | ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ \" ~ * ? : \\"
>> keyword.gsub!(/[+\-&|!(){}\[\]^"~*?:\\]/, " ")
=> "                                   "
```

Character classes (enclosed by `[]`) are easier to reason about in this case. You need to escape `-` and `[` and `]` and `\`.

Comment: If you put `-` at the beginning or the end of `[]` then you don't need to escape it. Also did you know that `gsub!` returns nil if there is no match?

Answer (score 0):

**\W = Any non-word character**

```
>> keyword = '+ - & | ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \\'
=> "+ - & | ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ \" ~ * ? : \\"
>> keyword.gsub!(/\W/," ")
=> "                                   "
```

Comment: does non-word mean non-latin chars? Does other language like Japanese/Chinese considered non-word?